# Maven site: delete

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have deployed the site (site-deploy on Jenkins) and I have generated a site into a folder, but now I want to clean the folder (delete the site). How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go onto this server and delete the folder where you deployed the site.

Comment: I guess I need to ask admin, thank you :). I just was wandering if I can do it without him :)